# Converting 32 bit dll to 64 bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, 32bit-64bit

I had to switch to Office 64 bit (2019, Professional Plus). I have a large number of VBA scripts and most of them make calls to an old 32 bit dll written in plain C language and compiled with the very old Developer Studio 97. I managed to recompile it with Visual Studio 2019 as a C++ dll at 64 bits and I faced 2 problems: the function MessageBox (and MessageBoxA) is flagged as "undefined". Workaround: I  temporarily replaced them with OutputDebugStringA and the DLL compiles fine.

Calling the function from VBA, it fails to load. Thanks to ProcessorMonitor I found my dll tried to load VCRUNTIME140D.dll and UCRBASED.dll. I downloaded them from the internet and I discovered I must place them in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16. But that was not enough! VCRUNTIME140D.dll **must** be placed in C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32 too!

At that point, my DLL works fine as 64 bit dll.

Next surprise was that, after a reboot, it once again failed to load due to missing VCRUNTIME140_APP.dll (please note no "D" after "140")! Downloaded and placed in  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16, the DLL works fine as expected.

I tried to compile it as "static" ('Code Generation' -> 'runtime library' -> 'multithreaded' instead 'multithreaded dll') but I got the error:
MSB8024 Using static version of the C++ runtime library is not supported.

Somewhere I read that VCRUNTIME140 is related to Visual Studio 2014... strange, but may be I miss some .obj from that version too in order to statically link? Why do I need elements from an older system?

Back to the MessageBox problem, I tried a simple c++ 64 bit console application and the exact same function is accepted and works as expected, so I guessed was some #ifdef in the header files that excludes the declaration in a dll. Moved the MessageBox declarations in my header file, the compilation is successful, but (as I could guess) a linker "unresolved external" for MessageBox shows up.

At this points, my questions are:
-Is it possible to create a 64 bit **static** .dll?
-Is it *normal* I have to download the above 3 dll's from the web and copy them in some directories?
-It it possible to use the plain MessageBox (handle, text, caption, buttons) in a 64 bit dll?

Thanks.

Comment: ***VCRUNTIME140D.dll and UCRBASED.dll*** Means you have a dependency on the debug runtime. Whatever code you are using should be rebuilt to the Release configuration.

Comment: ***I downloaded them from the internet*** This is actually a violation of the Visual Studio license. You should not download  these files. These files are supposed to be supplied by Visual Studio that you installed and are used for debugging. You need to install a newer version of Visual Studio.

Comment: The 140 is for Visual Studio 14.0, which is 2015.

Comment: A static DLL is a contradiction in terms.  DLLs should also always use the DLL version of the runtime so that it's shared with the app - having two different heaps for example will cause nothing but trouble.

Comment: @drescherjm Removed the 3 dll's, compiled in Release mode I get Runtime error 53. With Process Monitor, I see "excel.exe" tries to load VCRUNTIME140D.DLL. I think I have the latest version of Visual Studio: I downloaded it on october 5 from the official Microsoft site.

Comment: @rup Yes, in fact my one is 16.7.5 and I wonder why a just compiled dll doesn't try to load [the same?] modules but ...167... or something like that! There is no VCRUNTIME*.dll on my system!

Comment: `I downloaded them from the internet and placed....` It is not how you install a vc runtime redistribuable. You must download and install it instead of copy and place somewhere.

Comment: `VCRUNTIME140D.DLL` if there is a D before .dll you still have some type of Debug dll dependency.

Comment: It could be a solution type issue. The solution should be a Windows Desktop type, not a Windows Runtime or anything like that.

Comment: @rup From MSDN site: VCRUNTIME140.dll is one of the runtime libraries of Microsoft Visual Studio (VC++) 2015/2017/2019. Because Visual C++ 2015, 2017 and 2019 all share the same redistributable files. VC++ runtime libraries are DLL files required to run programs compiled with Microsoft VC++ / Visual Studio suite. In a fresh install, I have C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110 directory with bin, crt, include and lib sudirectorier, all containing hooks to 14.27...

Comment: You could go to Microsoft  to download [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads). And you coulld use [MessageBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox?redirectedfrom=MSDN) in dll. MessageBox is a WinAPI function.

Comment: @rustyx yes, that is **the** problem! VCRUNTIME140 **is** part of Visual Studio 2019 too. Now let me find how to switch to Windows Desktop type!

Comment: Do you mean to convert dll to exe?

Comment: @BarrnetChou, no, I don't mean transform a .dll to .exe. My an answer was to rustyx that, correctly, says it was a Solution Type problem. See above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, thanks to rustyx's intuition, I discovered I was using a "Solution" suitable for "app" development. (The string _APP inside the called dll name indicated just that!) I managed to switch to "Desktop" solution, and now the dll's loaded are without the _APP suffix. The MessageBox function works fine, without the need of any particular settings in libraries.

VCRUNTIME140D.DLL (debug version) and VCRUNTIME140.DLL (release version) are present in my installation installed while they **are** part of Visual Studio 2019 (as well as 2015 and 2017).

Finally, it is now possible to generate a static dll in this case, VCRUNTIME140.DLL (and many more) is not loaded at runtime but the same code is statically linked. Dumpbin shows it.
Dynamic linking:
USER32.dll
VCRUNTIME140.dll
api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
KERNEL32.dll
Static linking:
USER32.dll
KERNEL32.dll

All problems solved!

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.